# Regular Expression to match given word in last five words of pipe-delimited string

Tags: javascript, regex

Say we have a string

```
blue|blue|green|blue|blue|yellow|yellow|blue|yellow|yellow|
```

And we want to figure out whether the word "yellow" occurs in the last 5 words of the string, specifically by returning a capture group containing these occurences if any.

Is there a way to do that with a regex?

Update: I'm feeding a regex engine some rules. For various reasons I'm trying to work with the engine rather than go outside it, which would be my last resort.

Comment: (\w*)\| for the capture group but it needs to be go in reverse and be limited to the first five words.

Comment: "first five" (from your comment) or "last five" (from your question)? And why does it have to be a regex? Are you dealing with some sort of brain damaged API?

Comment: See my update to my question. Last five.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want to know if there's at least one match or you want to know the exact number of matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/\b(yellow)\|(?=(?:\w+\|){0,4}$)/g
```

This will return one hit for each `yellow|` that's followed by fewer than five words (per your definition of "word").  This assumes the sequence always ends with a pipe; if that's not the case, you might want to change it to:

```
/\b(yellow)(?=(?:\|\w+){0,4}\|?$)/g
```

---

**EDIT (in response to comment):** The definition of a "word" in this solution is arbitrary, and doesn't really correspond to real-world usage.  To allow for hyphenated words like "real-world" you could use this:

```
/\b(yellow)\|(?=(?:\w+(?:-\w+)*\|){0,4}$)/g
```

...or, for this particular job, you could define a word as *one or more of any characters except pipes*:

```
/\b(yellow)\|(?=(?:[^|]+\|){0,4}$)/g
```

Comment: Nice. Took some puzzling to figure out what you did but it works. Interesting side note: Rubular.com returns 'yellow' without the pipe while the same thing in javascript returns 'yellow|' with the pipe. Strange because the pipe isn't in our capture group.

Comment: Apparently, Rubular is returning the contents of the highest-numbered capturing group (`$1`), which doesn't include the pipe.  JavaScript is giving you the overall match (`$0` or `$&`), which does includes it.  (That's with the first regex, of course; with the second regex you shouldn't see the pipe in either case.)

Comment: Just discovered a wrinkle with the string data. Sometimes what I called words actually contain dashes, which I think means using \w+ is out since it will stop at the dash in, say, 'yel-low' while I need for it to get 'yel-low' in its entirety. Tried replacing \w+\| in your first regex with a non-greedy capture like \/.*?\| but no luck. It captures 'yel-low' anywhere in the string, not just in the last five 'words'.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use a Regex for such a simple thing.

Simply split on the pipe, and check with `indexOf`:

```
var group = 'blue|blue|green|blue|blue|yellow|yellow|blue|yellow|yellow';

if ( group.split('|').slice(-5).indexOf('yellow') == -1 ) {
    alert('Not there :(');
} else {
    alert('Found!!!');
}
```

**Note:** `indexOf` is not natively supported in IE < 9, but support for it can be [added very easily](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility).

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer - it has to be a regex for various reasons. And it has to return its results as a capture group that is either empty (if yellow doesn't occur in the last words) or contains the number of occurences of the word yellow in the last five words of the string.

Comment: @Roxicus - please put this NEW requirement into your actual question (use the Edit button) where anyone trying to answer your question can see it.   Since it seems kind of ususual to us for you to insist on a regex solution when it's not the most straightforward way to solve a problem, you might want to explain why too.  That will either prevent answers that don't interest you or solicit other alternatives that could meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of a way to do this with a single regular expression, but you can form one for each of the last five positions and sum the matches.

```
var string = "blue|blue|green|blue|blue|yellow|yellow|blue|yellow|yellow|";

var regexes = [];
regexes.push(/(yellow)\|[^|]+\|[^|]+\|[^|]+\|[^|]+\|$/);
regexes.push(/(yellow)\|[^|]+\|[^|]+\|[^|]+\|$/);
regexes.push(/(yellow)\|[^|]+\|[^|]+\|$/);
regexes.push(/(yellow)\|[^|]+\|$/);
regexes.push(/(yellow)\|$/);

var count = 0;
var regex;
while (regex = regexes.shift()) {
  if (string.match(regex)) {
    count++;
  }
}

console.log(count);
```

Should find four matches.